# Arquivo php que cria html, como faço pra informação contida vir do banco de dados?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como faço para o html criado por esse php ao inves de conter o texto entre as aspa, ele contenha uma informação que vem do meu banco de dados.

```
<?php
# Nome do arquivo html
$pagename = "pastatest/paginahtml.html";

# Texto a ser salvo no arquivo
$texto = "<h1>texto que vai conter no html</h1>";

#Criar o arquivo
$fp = fopen($pagename , "w");
$fw = fwrite($fp, $texto);

#Verificar se o arquivo foi salvo.
if($fw == strlen($texto)) {
   echo 'Arquivo criado com sucesso!!';
}else{
   echo 'falha ao criar arquivo';
}
?>
```

Comment: Já fez a conexão com o banco de dados? essa é a parte que tem dúvida??

Comment: não eu ja tenho a conexão com banco de dados, meu problema é com select from, só que como pode ver a variavel $texto só mando pro aquivo criado o texto que tiver entre as " " e quero que esse texto no caso venha do banco de dados

Comment: @cadeira13 Se possível [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/153302/edit) a pergunta e coloque o código que faz a conexão, e também o `select ..` que você quer salvar no arquivo. Veja também o **[tour]**!.

Answer (score 2):

Faça um `SELECT`

```
<?php
# Nome do arquivo html
$pagename = "pastatest/paginahtml.html";

# Pega texto no Banco de dados

$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE id='1'"); //Em id vc coloca qual registro do banco de dados você quer pegar.
$query->execute();

$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

# Texto a ser salvo no arquivo
$texto = "<h1>".$row['texto']."</h1>";

#Criar o arquivo
$fp = fopen($pagename , "w");
$fw = fwrite($fp, $texto);

#Verificar se o arquivo foi salvo.
if($fw == strlen($texto)) {
   echo 'Arquivo criado com sucesso!!';
}else{
   echo 'falha ao criar arquivo';
}
?>
```

O `SELECT` eu fiz com base em uma conexão PDO. Faça uma query de acordo com sua conexão com o Banco de dados (MySQL, MySQLi, PDO, etc.)

Comment: gente eu fiz alguma coisa errada ta dando esse erro >> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\AppServ\www\test\criar.php on line 21

Comment: @cadeira13 você primeiro tem que criar uma conexão PDO e atribui-lá a variavel $conn

Comment: sim eu ja consegui rsrs criei aqui a conexão pdo, deu tudo certo obgd

Answer (score -1):

O arquivo usando mysql, ficará assim:

```
<?php
# Nome do arquivo html
$pagename = "pastatest/paginahtml.html";

# Texto a ser salvo no arquivo
$selecionar = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
$conectar = mysql_query($selecionar);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($conectar);
$texto = $array['texto'];

#Criar o arquivo
$fp = fopen($pagename , "w");
$fw = fwrite($fp, $texto);

#Verificar se o arquivo foi salvo.
if($fw == strlen($texto)) {
   echo 'Arquivo criado com sucesso!!';
}else{
   echo 'falha ao criar arquivo';
}
?>
```

Nota: mysql é obsoleto. PDO ou mysqli são mais recomendados.

Comment: gente obrigado pela resposta, fiquei satisfeito obgd

Comment: se puderem me enviar conexão com a db estou usando essa em PDO `$host = "localhost";
$db   = "devmedia";
$user = "root";
$pass = "88319076";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysql_select_db($db, $con);`